# Issue trying to send android push notification when time is about to reach a value

Tags: java, android

I have a Project management app with Java android and I'd like to implement a push notification feature where a user can select the intervals in which they would like to be reminded before the projects due date is reached.

At the moment when creating a project, a user can select to be reminded 2 weeks before a due date, 1 week, 1 day etc.. and then it should send notifications when it's time (similar to the Notion app if you've used it).

My question is, how do I send a push notification when these conditions are met, I'm aware i would need some type of service to continuously check if certain interval is reached even if the app is closed so the notification can be sent, but unsure of the full process.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to send notification even if app is closed you should use worker class.
Here is the implementation:

```
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
```

then create a class that extends the worker class. Create this class's constructor and doWork methods. Create the showNotification method inside the doWork method. Thus, even if the application is closed, you will be able to send notifications within the time intervals you set. The minimum notification time interval is 15 minutes.

here is the MyWorkerNotification Class:

```
public class MyWorkerNotification extends Worker {

public MyWorkerNotification(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    showNotification();

    return Result.success();
}

private void showNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent targetActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        String chanelId = "chanelId";
        String chanelName = "chanelName";
        String chanelDescription = "chanelDescription";
        int chanelPriority = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationChannel chanel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(chanelId);

        if(chanel == null) {
            chanel = new NotificationChannel(chanelId, chanelName, chanelPriority);
            chanel.setDescription(chanelDescription);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(chanel);
        }

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), chanelId);

        builder.setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications)
                .setContentIntent(targetActivity)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


    } else {
        //Depreceted
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

        builder.setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications)
                .setContentIntent(targetActivity)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    }

    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());

}
```

}

and here is the MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());

    //Button Show Notification
    buttonShowNotificcation();

}

public void buttonShowNotificcation() {


    activityMainBinding.buttonShowNotification.setOnClickListener(view -> {


        //Notification Request
        WorkRequest request= new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkerNotification.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(request);


        
    });
}
```

}

so when you click buttonShowNotification in this application, the first notification will come within 10 seconds. You will then be able to send notifications every 15 minutes, even if the app is running in the background.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it out and i get the notifications sent each 15 min, but for my use case I'm still struggling to implement it properly.


So for a project, a user can select a remind me option for 2 weeks, 1 weeks, 1 day, 1 hour and 30 minutes, which means something would need to constantly be checking for that conditions on each project so it can send a notification with the specific project title and some other info.

I don't know if it makes sense to you, but i'm still trying to figure that out

Comment: yes, i understand you. I can't comment further as I don't know the specific reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Managed to get it working with a Foreground service and a timer to check frequently if a project reached a time interval.